# After successfully subscribing to Microsoft graph notifications with application I receive no notifications

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to receive notifications from Ms Graph. I want to create background service/daemon which connects to Graph with its own identity.
I'm using developer account. I've successfully created an application in AAD. I've added necessary permissions to my app.
For simplicity I'm using Postman to make REST requests to Graph. I've successfully authenticated with my app via:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mytoken}/oauth2/token
```

And received Authorization token. I can successfully execute Graph queries, like read and write messages of all users.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/93ffed3b-5aec-458c-a5eb-691cd610cd50/messages
```

I've created 2 subscriptions. And I can see those in a list.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/

{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions",
"value": [
    {
        "id": "67d395ae-0fad-438e-8f23-175dd2b43172",
        "resource": "/users/93ffed3b-5aec-458c-a5eb-691cd610cd50/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
        "applicationId": "991ead1f-14b0-4934-a471-c749edcbb352",
        "changeType": "created",
        "clientState": null,
        "notificationUrl": "https://831327fd.ngrok.io/notification/listen",
        "expirationDateTime": "2018-12-13T23:00:00Z",
        "creatorId": "fc01f0e2-2b2c-4dc1-a18c-75529fb75953"
    },
    {
        "id": "75b01b91-6595-4ce0-98b3-772731071607",
        "resource": "/users/93ffed3b-5aec-458c-a5eb-691cd610cd50/messages",
        "applicationId": "991ead1f-14b0-4934-a471-c749edcbb352",
        "changeType": "created",
        "clientState": null,
        "notificationUrl": "https://831327fd.ngrok.io/notification/listen",
        "expirationDateTime": "2018-12-13T23:00:00Z",
        "creatorId": "fc01f0e2-2b2c-4dc1-a18c-75529fb75953"
    }
]
```

}

I'm using ngrok to tunnel requests to my local dev environment.
I've send several emails to an account which I subscribed to in subscriptions. But I've received no notifications.
How can I troubleshoot it? Is there a problem on MS Graph side, was it attempting so send me Notifications Or not? Is there a problem with my account or application configuration?

Today I see notifications about yesterdays' emails. For some unknown reason I received notifications after several hours. But question remains. Is there a way I can troubleshoot Notification scenario and see why MS Graph did not sent them to me?

Comment: Did you respond to the initial subscription validation message wth an `HTTP 200`?

Comment: If you are able to provide some time ranges for when you created the subscriptions and expected notifications, we can investigate further.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur yes, I did respond with 200, otherwise notification is not created and I can't see it in a list.

Comment: @Trey I'll write time in UTC, I created my subscriptions at about 2018-12-13T15:00:00. And then started to send emails to a mailbox I subscribed to. Notification expiration as you see is on same day 2018-12-13T23:00:00Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours everything started to work properly. It seams there is some internal stuff in MS Graph or Azure that after you create an Application and subscribe via it to emails, it's not starting to work instantly.